# PSQLException: The column name start_value was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc

I am getting Postgresql Exception, when spring-boot maven application is starting up.

Maven Dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Property file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

Exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name start_value was not found in this ResultSet.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2748) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2631) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetStartValueSize(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.sequenceInformationList(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:403) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at
```

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is in the stacktrace: 42.2.16

Comment: Postgreql version - 9.0

Comment: Have you tried using `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect`?

Comment: Yes same error with org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect

Answer (score 1):

Use the below custom class and pass it in the property.

```
package com.abc.def;

import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorNoOpImpl;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.SequenceInformationExtractor;

public class PostgresqlCustomDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {

    public String getQuerySequencesString() {
        return "select * from all_sequences";
    }

    public SequenceInformationExtractor getSequenceInformationExtractor() {
        return SequenceInformationExtractorNoOpImpl.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Put fully qualified class name in below property :

`p.put("hibernate.dialect","com.abc.def.PostgresqlCustomDialect");`